# Subtract 2 hours from time in php

Tags: php, time

I want to subtract 2 hours from given time for example I am getting time 2016-07-15T06:20:00 and I want to subtract 2 hours from it like 2016-07-15T04:20:00

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `DateTime` class for this.

```
 $DateTime = new DateTime();
 $DateTime->modify('-2 hours');
 echo $DateTime->format("Y-m-dTH:i:s");
```

Answer (score 6):

Another way is

```
echo date('Y-m-dTH:i:s', strtotime('-2 hours', strtotime('2016-07-15T06:20:00')));
```

or

```
echo date('Y-m-dTH:i:s', strtotime('2016-07-15T06:20:00') - 7200);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DateInterval` to subtract hours and minutes (which is zero in your case) in `php`, like this :

```
$date = new DateTime();
$tosub = new DateInterval('PT2H10M'); // 2hr 10 mins
$date->sub($tosub);
echo $date->format("Y-m-dTH:i:s");
```