# PHP subtract unknown time from datetime

Tags: php, datetime

So, I'm creating a booking system. When I retrieve this booking from the database, I need to check if the current date and time is closer to the actual booked date and time.

On the admin dashboard, the admins specify how much time earlier the client can make a checkin, let's say for example, 30minutes. But this time can be different. Can be 1hour, 2hours, 10minutes.

When I get the result from the database I get them like this:

```php
$date_schedule = '2021-03-25 15:40:00'; // Can be any date in the future as well;
$time_to_check = '00:30:00'; // Can be '01:05:00', whatever the admins set as time_to_check;

// Expected result
'2021-03-25 15:10:00';
```

I tried subtracting this but I didn't made it work.. This is what I did.

```php
$current_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$booking_date = '2021-03-25 15:00:00'; // From database
$time_to_check = '00:30:00'; // From database
$hours = explode(':', $time_to_check);
$data_check = date($booking_date, strtotime('-' . $hours[0] . ' hour -' . $hours[1] . ' minutes'));
```

But with this, $data_check returns the same value as `$booking_date`, it's not subtracting the time.

Comment: That's because the first argument to the `date` function is *format*. You give it a literal date, and that's what it outputs, regardless of the timestamp that follows. And the timestamp you create subtracts from the *current time*. Use the `DateTime` class, you can achieve the same thing with the `modify` method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subtract 2 hours from time in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38372971/subtract-2-hours-from-time-in-php)

Comment: The duplicate deals with a fixed amount, but the principle is identical, and you've shown you know how to build the modification string dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your date to DateTime to make some operations on it :

```
function changeDate($date, $interval) {

    $datetime   = new DateTime($date);
    $values     = explode(':', $interval);

    $datetime->modify("-$values[0] hours -$values[1] minutes -$values[2] seconds");

    return $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

}

$date   = changeDate('2021-03-25 15:00:00', '00:30:00');
echo $date; // 2021-03-25 14:30:00

$date   = changeDate('2021-03-25 15:00:00', '01:30:00');
echo $date; // 2021-03-25 13:30:00

$date   = changeDate('2021-03-25 15:00:00', '02:30:15');
echo $date; // 2021-03-25 12:29:45
```

You can find documentation here https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Comment: Those three separate calls to `modify` could be made into one. You also have a typo next to minutes, you use `.` instead of `-`.

Comment: Didn't knew how to do it with DateTime, it's easier now and it worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just convert the timestamp to Unix time, and then subtract 30 minutes in seconds (30 * 60) from the Unix time.

Like this:

```
$date =  '2021-03-25 15:10:00';
$timestamp = strtotime($date);
$timestamp = ($timestamp - (30 * 60));
echo gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);
```

EDIT: If you are in an odd timezone, like me (GMT+0100) add or subtract difference;

```
$timestamp = (($timestamp - (30 * 60)) + (1 * 60 * 60))
```